# How to store infinity in a BigDecimal (Java)?

Tags: java, algorithm, exception, bigdecimal, infinity

I am writing algorithms inside methods that return BigDecimal values but now and again the result calculated will be + or - infinity.
Rather than the program crashing I'd like to catch the exception and return infinity as a value like the way you could if the method was returning a double.

eg Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

So how do I store infinity in a BigDecimal? Or is there another way of doing this?

```
public static BigDecimal myalgorithm(){

//code to store infinity in a BigDecimal
//return the BigDecimal holding infinity 

}
```

Comment: `BigDecimal` has no way to represent infinity.

Comment: When would the result calculated be + or - infinity?  `BigDecimal.divide` will throw an arithmetic exception if the divisor is zero.  Other than that how would you calculate + or - infinity?

Comment: Yes you see due to the nature of the algorithms there can be divisions by zero sometimes.  Currently I'm just catching the arithmetic exception and returning + or - 999

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`BigDecimal` doesn't have the concept of infinity. I can think of three options:

1. The *cleanest* approach is probably to derive your own `MyBigDecimal` class, adding an infinity flag telling you if the instance contains infinity, and overriding the methods to which it would be relevant (which would be most of them, I would think), using the base class's version when you're not holding infinity and your own code when you are.
2. You could use `null` as a flag value in your code, although that might be a bit of a pain. E.g.:

   ```
   if (theBigDecimal == null) {
       // It's infinity, deal with that
   }
   else {
       // It's finite, deal with that
   }
   ```
3. If you're already using `null` for something else, you could have a `BigDecimal` instance that doesn't actually contain infinity, but which you pretend containts it, and use `==` to check against it. E.g.:

   ```
   // In your class somewhere:
   static final BigDecimal INFINITE_BIG_DECIMAL = new BigDecimal(); // Value doesn't matter

   // Then:
   if (theBigDecimal == INFINITE_BIG_DECIMAL) {
       // It's infinity, deal with that
   }
   else {
       // It's finite, deal with that
   }
   ```

Comment: Why not just use Double?

Comment: @MGorgon: I assume the OP is using `BigDecimal` *for a reason* (arbitrary precision, for instance).

Comment: @ MGorgon: I'm taking in very large numbers into these algorithms and would prefer to be able to cope with them and still have precision.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: The problem is, what do I actually write (code wise) in the part where you say //It's infinity, deal with that.  Because I still will not be able to return a value of infinity that way

Comment: @user2989759: Your code will need to handle the concept of infiniteness. As I say, the cleanest way to do that is to derive from `BigDecimal` and add the concept to the class. Then you can (for instance) have a class-wide `MyBigDecimal.Infinity` instance, and in (say) the `divide` method: `if (this.isInfinite) { return MyBigDecimal.Infinity; }` then `return super.divide(divisor);` (for the non-infinite case). (You might also want to handle the case of the divisor being infinite, of course.)

Comment: If you do (1), you will need to handle the concept of NaN as well to handle operations where both operands are infinite (divide and subtract in this case have undefined results), or throw errors in these cases.

Comment: @wakjah: Yeah, and positive and negative infinity, and pick your poison on dividing by infinity (error? 0? ɛ?), and...

Answer (score -3):

An approach to the problem would be, to just use a really large number in this case:

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(negative ? Double.MIN_VALUE : Double.MAX_VALUE)
```

As BigDecimal does not have a real maximum or minimum value, you can use the ones of double.

Important with this approach is, that it doesn't really solve the problem of representing infinity, but depending on the usecase it can solve the problem well enough. I used it for the same usecase as you have mentioned above.

Actually double does more or less the same when calling intValue on it. In that case it will just represent the maximum integer.

Comment: `Double.MIN_VALUE` is > 0

Comment: this is a very wrong approach. Double and BigDecimal are absolutely different by nature and are interchangeable only in narrow set of values.